# Can i use group_concat inside another group_concat in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So i have a query like this:

```sql
select
  p.identifier,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    '[' ||
    '{"thumbnail":' ||
    '"' ||
    ifnull(s.thumbnail,'null') ||
    '"' ||
    ',"title:' ||
    '"' ||
    s.title ||
    '","content": [' ||
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      '{"text":' ||
      ifnull(c.text,'null') ||
      '", "image":' || 
      ifnull(c.image,'null') ||
      '", "caption": "' ||
      ifnull(c.caption,'null') ||
      '"},'
    ) ||
    ']},'
  )
from pois as p
join  stories as s on p.identifier = s.poiid
join content c on s.storyid = c.storyid
group by s.storyid
```

And i got and error:

> in prepare, misuse of aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT()

To see clearly i have a big object named POIS every POI have multiple STORIES and every STORY have multiple CONTENTS, and i want to display x rows(how many pois i have) and inside the column have every story that is connected to their poi(and every content inside stories) and i need this in json format so i can parse the database query and read back into my object.

I hope its clear what is my problem and you can help me.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `GROUP_CONCAT` function; its equivalent is `STRING_AGG` and no, it can't be nested (you would need to use a CTE or derived table). Though I suspect you *aren't* using SQL Server.

Comment: the error message "misuse of aggregate function" seems to be SQLLite

Comment: Either way, if you would have formatted your query properly it would have been obvious what the issue is: you have an aggregate inside an aggregate, which is logically not possible. Probably you need to pre-aggregate `content` in a derived table, but hard to say without sample data and expected results

Comment: i posted an answer with an update with my query, i changed it to json_group_array, can you take a look on that please?

Comment: Without sample data and expected results we cannot help

Answer (score 0):

So i changed the query to something like this:

```
SELECT p.identifier, (
    SELECT json_group_array(json_object('id', s.storyid))
    FROM stories AS s
    WHERE s.poiid=p.identifier
) as stories,
(
    SELECT json_group_array(json_object('id', c.contentid, 'storyId', s.storyid))
    FROM content AS c
    JOIN stories AS s ON c.storyid=s.storyid
    WHERE s.poiid=p.identifier
) as contents
FROM pois AS p
GROUP BY p.identifier
```

this is my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fshl.png)

but the 3 rd column i would like to put inside the second(every pois have multiple stories and every story have one or multiple contents, so the contents should be inside their stories.